# Is open command suitable for binary file operations

Tags: c, linux, file, sockets, system

I have an FTP application sending binary files over the TCP sockets.

I have opened the file using open and reading the binary files as if they were string files (Program works fine with text files) and then sending them over TCP.

But I'm struggling with the output at the other end. I wanted to know if fopen is better suited for binary files or binary files can be treated as text files.

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: You need to send a **TYPE I** command to the remote FTP server if you do not want it to do any transformations on the data. The default is **TYPE A N**.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, there is no notion of binary or text file (contrarily to Windows, where it is relevant), which appears only in the C99 standard [fopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) function which says:

> The *mode* string can also include the letter 'b' either as a last
>          character or as a character between the characters in any of the two-
>          character strings described above.  This is strictly for
>          compatibility with C89 and has no effect; the 'b' is ignored on all
>          POSIX conforming systems, including Linux.  (Other systems may treat
>          text files and binary files differently, and adding the 'b' may be a
>          good idea if you do I/O to a binary file and expect that your program
>          may be ported to non-UNIX environments.)

Of course you can use the [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) syscall directly (BTW, `fopen` uses it).

However, binary files are much less portable (e.g. because of [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) issues) than textual ones. Read about [serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization), so perhaps prefer textual formats and [protocols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_protocol) e.g. [JSON](http://json.org/) to binary ones.

Regarding FTP on the client side, consider perhaps using existing libraries like [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/)

Comment: Text vs. binary mode is important on Windows, though:  it determines whether `"\n"` gets translated to `"\r\n"` (the Windows line delimiter).

Comment: I know that, but the OP tagged his question with Linux.

Comment: Binary files are not significantly less portable than text files nowadays—architectures where a byte is not an octet are rare today. What is true is that you have to pay a lot more attention when parsing binary files than when parsing text files because you have to watch out for endianess issues.